# What contains a vector's element that is moved?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    // create the vector
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr< int > > v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i )
    {
        std::unique_ptr< int > newItem( new int(i) );
        v.push_back( std::move( newItem ) );
    }

    std::cout<<"vector's size before the move = " << v.size() << std::endl;

    // move one item
    auto it = move( v[2] );
    std::cout<<"moved element = " << *it << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"vector's size after the move = " << v.size() << std::endl;
if ( nullptr == v[2].get())
    std::cout<<"it is nullptr" << std::endl;
}
```

The above example is moving one element out of the vector, but the vector's size remained the same.

What contains the moved element after the move? Is it an undefined behaviour to access that element? Is it nullptr (the example prints it is null)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the vector. `std::uniqe_ptr` defines the state of the object after a move, it's set to null (20.7.1/4).

In general, an object that has been moved from has a valid but unspecified state. So unless the type documents cases in which it cannot be accessed, you can access it. Particular classes arguably should give more detail of that state whenever possible, but what vector relies on is that:

1. the object can be moved from again (otherwise the vector wouldn't be able to reallocate)
2. the object can still be destroyed when the vector is destroyed.

So, for a type other than `unique_ptr` in the vector, you should probably think to yourself that the resulting value of the source of the move can be any of:

1. an "empty" or "zero" value of the type,
2. the original value,
3. the original value of the *target* of the move,
4. some other value of the type that you didn't think of.

If you still think it's *worth* accessing a value that might be any of those, go ahead ;-)

Comment: The rationale behind this is that a moved element must be in a destroyable state.

Comment: +1. Though, I dare to say that a move assignment should *not* be equivalent to a swap because that may leave some resources allocated for an unexpectedly long time. So, case (3) is not something I would expect.

Comment: @sellobitze: no, I didn't intend for that to be an example of common practice, just as something that is legal and that therefore you are not entitled to be all that outraged by if it does happen.